# Why is IEntityCollection internal / How to find EntityCollection<T>.Count?

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

In RIA services the [`EntityCollection<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422772(VS.91).aspx)  is defined as follows :

```
public sealed class EntityCollection<TEntity> : IEntityCollection, 
                                                IEnumerable<TEntity>, 
                                                IEnumerable,  
                                                INotifyCollectionChanged,  
                                                INotifyPropertyChanged where TEntity :  
                                                global::System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Entity
```

I have a Silverlight converter which sets `Visibility` dependent upon the number of items in a list.

```
 if (value is EntityCollection<CustomerFeedbackDetail>)
 {
      visible = (value as EntityCollection<CustomerFeedbackDetail>).Count > 0;
 }
```

**But wait - I want it to be generic for any EntityCollection.** Uh oh - `IEntityCollection` is internal and not accessible to us. EntityCollection doesn't even implement ICollection.

Am I stuck without using reflection (which I really would rather not do since this may get called many times a second in some cases).

I'm pretty sure I do have to use reflection to make this generic - so in that case why would `IEntityCollection` be internal? Oversight?

Comment: Making `IEntityCollection` internal was not an oversight; failing to implement `ICollection` was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using reflection, you could just implement the function yourself. You don't care about the count, just that it's non-zero. Simply rewrite the `Enumberable.Any(IEnumerable<T>)` function to take non-generic `IEnumerable`:

```
public static bool Any(this System.Collections.IEnumerable source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    return source.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
}
```

Then in your converter you would have:

```
if (value is EntityCollection<CustomerFeedbackDetail>) 
{ 
    visible = (value as IEnumerable).Any(); 
}
```

Comment: it didn't like the 'using', but works apart from that! thanks!
ps. what kind of exception handling mechanism are you using to have Error.ArgumentNull ?

Comment: some interesting notes on 'Any()' vs 'Count' from Phil Haack : http://haacked.com/archive/2010/06/10/checking-for-empty-enumerations.aspx

Comment: The original code was just a copy of `Enumberable.Any(IEnumerable<T>)` with the `<T>` removed. Since `IEnumerable` doesn't implement `IDisposable`, the `using` didn't belong. I fixed the code and eliminated external dependencies.

Comment: Good answer, however you should test whether the `Enumerator` returned by `GetEnumerator` implements `IDisposable` and dispose the `Enumerator` if it does.